# Adding custom attributes to asp.NET RadioButton control

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I want to add a custom attribute to an asp.net RadioButton called `Key` which I'm using client-side for an ajax request.

What I'm finding is that my aspx markup which is the following:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoPost" GroupName=PreferredContactMethod" value="Post" onclick="DoStuff(this)" runat="server" />
```

gets rendered in the page as

```
<span Key="ContactMethod">
   <input id="rdoPost" type="radio" name="PreferredContactMethod"" value="Post" onclick="DoStuff(this);" />
</span>
```

whereas I'd expected (and hoped) to get the following

```
<input id="rdoPost" type="radio" Key="ContactMethod" name="PreferredContactMethod"" value="Post" onclick="DoStuff(this);" />
```

I've tried the same thing with an asp TextBox control and it works exactly as I'd expect simply adding the `Key="myKey"` attribute to the `<input type="text"/>` element.

Is there a way around this with the standard RadioButton control, or will I have to inherit from the standard one to achieve the markup I'm wanting?

Also... (sorry to ask two questions at the same time), is adding non-standard attributes to html markup a bad idea anyway? Currently I'm using these attributes in JavaScript in the following way:

```
var key = rdoPost.Key;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found from the question/answer below that the easiest way to do this is via the code-behind using the `InputAttributes` property as follows:

```
rdoPost.InputAttributes.Add("class", "myCheckBoxClass");
```

[Why does ASP.Net RadioButton and CheckBox render inside a Span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997342/why-does-asp-net-radiobutton-and-checkbox-render-inside-a-span#1711516)

Comment: Yes, this is helpful for RadioButton, but not RadioButtonList.

Comment: I've been coding webforms for like 10 years and just now found this attribute. Wow.

Comment: It's funny that this does work. I have a user control for a text input and didnt need to do this at all, just used `Attribute` instead of `InputAttribute`