# CSS ''background-color" attribute not working on checkbox inside <div>

Tags: html, css, checkbox, background-color

The heading pretty much explains it. I have a couple of checkboxes inside a scrollable div. But for some reasons the 'background-color' attribute doesn't work. Although the 'margin-top' does seem to work...

Just puzzling me how one attribute can work and another not. It's also not like the div has it's own set of background color attributes that could potentially over ride the checkboxes attributes.

Anyways, below is my HTML (which is generated by JSP):

```
<div class="listContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" class="oddRow">item1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="evenRow">item2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="oddRow">item3<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="evenRow">item4<br/>
    ...
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.listContainer {
            border:2px solid #ccc;
            width:340px;
            height: 225px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

.oddRow {
            margin-top: 5px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

.evenRow{
            margin-top: 5px;
            background-color: #9FFF9D;
        }
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/34389136/4947434

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A checkbox does not have background color.

But to add the effect, you may wrap each checkbox with a `div` that has color:

```
<div class="evenRow">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="oddRow">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="evenRow">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="oddRow">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: I need 15rep before I can give you an upvote, but thanks! Did what you suggested and it worked perfectly...

Comment: With me the checkbox bg is still grey - only the area around the checkbox will change background from the div... `<div style="background-color: #ffffff;"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.toTenant" style="width:25px; height:25px; margin-top:8px; background-color:#FFFFFF" value=""></div>`

Comment: @mariazahid I am also stuck on this,the background color of huking checkbox

Comment: This can be done now, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70855040/4826740

Answer (score 21):

In addition to the currently accepted answer: You can set border and background of a checkbox/radiobutton, but how it is rendered in the end depends on the browser. For example, if you set a red background on a checkbox

- IE will show a red border instead
- Opera will show a red background as intended
- Firefox, Safari and Chrome will do nothing

[This German language article](http://www.css4you.de/wsradio/) compares a few browsers and explains at least the IE behavior. It maybe bit older (still including Netscape), but when you test around you'll notice that not much has changed. Another comparison can be found [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/).

Answer (score 19):

You can use peseudo elements like this:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 27px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: #9FFF9D;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  content: "\2714";
}
```

```html
<label>Checkbox label
      <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
```

Comment: no, you can't. INPUT's are not allowed to have children. Chrome realisation is a bug.

Answer (score 12):

After so much trouble i got it.

```css
    .purple_checkbox:after {
      content: " ";
      background-color: #5C2799;
      display: inline-block;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    
    .purple_checkbox:checked:after {
      content: "\2714";
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.15);
      border-radius: 3px;
      height: 12px;
      display: block;
      width: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 9px;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" class="purple_checkbox">
```

It will be like this when checked with this code.
[image]

Answer (score 11):

### My solution

Initially posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927978/3783833).

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background: #2aa1c0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 40%;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  display: block;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><br>
<input type="checkbox" checked><br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled><br>
<input type="checkbox" disabled checked><br>
```

Comment: If someone could advice why my text is not aligned after the checkbox, I'd love to know! CSS beginner here.

Answer (score 5):

### 2022 - there is a much better solution to this problem now

Just use the `accent-color` property and make sure you achieve proper [contrast ratios](https://contrast-ratio.com/) for accessibility:

```css
.blue-checkbox {
    accent-color: #00eaff;
    height: 30px; /* not needed */
    width: 30px; /* not needed */
}
```

```html
<input class="blue-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to change the checkmark color as well?

Comment: @DatLam I'm not aware of a way to control that. The browser seems to do it's best guess

Comment: Man oh Man, you're a life saver. That's brilliant

Answer (score 1):

We can provide background color from the css file. Try this one,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            input[type="checkbox"] {
                width: 25px;
                height: 25px;
                background: gray;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                -moz-appearance: none;
                appearance: none;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                position: relative;
                left: -5px;
                top: -5px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
                background: blue;
            }
            .checkbox-container {
                position: absolute;
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 20px;
                width: 25px;
                height: 25px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="checkbox-container">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best solution to change background checkbox color

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 12px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  input[type=checkbox]:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 0;
    content: " ";
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    padding: 0px 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  
  input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
   content: "✓";
   font-size: 12px;
  }
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a bus<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving another answer here

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  content: "\00a0\2714";
}
```

Answer (score -4):

When you input the body tag, press space just one time without closing the tag and input `bgcolor="red"`, just for instance. Then choose a diff color for your font.

Comment: Don't do this. Besides this not working for `<input type="checkbox">` in all browsers, there's a larger issue: it's important to [keep your styling separate from your markup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15170354/129086).