# Bring mat-icon / button to the front

Tags: css, angular-material2

I have this code:

```
<button style="z-index: 999999" mat-fab color="primary">
  <mat-icon style="z-index: 999999" aria-label="left">chevron_left</mat-icon>
</button>
```

but it's still resulting in this:

[image]

I want to get the chevron icon to the front, but I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Try setting the z-index of the card

Comment: You should also show what your code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

**Important note:** You are strongly advised not to use inline `style` attributes. Please use classes instead. [Reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170261/why-is-using-the-style-attribute-in-html-bad)

---

One thing you can do is, as I said in the comment above, try to set a `z-index` for the `<mat-card>` which is lower than the `z-index` of the FAB (aka a [*Floating Action Button*](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html)):

```html
<mat-card style="z-index: 9999">
  <!-- ... -->
</mat-card>

<!-- FAB -->
<button style="z-index: 999999" mat-fab color="primary">
  <mat-icon style="z-index: 999999" aria-label="left">chevron_left</mat-icon>
</button>
```

[Demo (see `styles.scss`)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zindex-problem-so?file=styles.scss)

Comment: what's the FAB?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Floating Action Button. https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html