# Expand/collapse a Div by clicking on an image

Tags: javascript

I added the following code to expand/collapse a Div by clicking on an image. this works well, but one problem is that the Div is shown by default, and I need to change the JS code, so that, the Div will be hidden by default, and only become visible when clicking on the image. If possible, please also help me on how to adjust the speed in which the Div expands or collapse.

```js
function toggle5(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
  var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
  if (ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="https:/PublishingImages/env3.png">';
  } else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="Supplier_Compliance/PublishingImages/env3.png">';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="headerDivImg">
  <a id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle5('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');">
    <img src="https://teams.connect.te.com/sites/BPDev/PublishingImages/attention1.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="contentDivImg" style="display: block;">This demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.</div>
```

Comment: use `display: none` instead of `display: block` for default hidden div and use `transition` in CSS to adjust the speed in which the Div expands or collapse

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. i  made the change and it works as expected! would you please also explain how to use transition in CSS to adjust the speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Jquery then you will be able to do it easily and you will be able to adjust the speed of expanded and collapsed div.

First of all Add Jquery.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add you HTML..

```
<a id="imageDivLink">

   <img height="100" src="https://visualpharm.com/assets/552/Expand-595b40b65ba036ed117d1be8.svg"> 

</a>


<div id="contentDivImg">

This demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing  your div dynamically via JavaScript.his demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.his demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your.

</div>
```

Add jquery code inside your body tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#imageDivLink").click(function(){

       $( "#contentDivImg" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
         // Animation complete.
       });

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use HTML attributes such as `style` or `onclick`, etc. They're ancient and discouraged for multiple reasons. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) (about `onclick`) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170261/why-is-using-the-style-attribute-in-html-bad) (about `style`)

Use an [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) instead.

---

To hide the div per default, use `display: none`. Don't use the `style` attribute as explained above. Either use a seperate CSS file or the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) tag instead.

```js
function toggle5(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
  var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
  if (ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="https:/PublishingImages/env3.png">';
  } else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="Supplier_Compliance/PublishingImages/env3.png">';
  }
}

// Add the EventListener to your element that toggles the div
document.getElementById('imageDivLink').addEventListener('click', () => toggle5('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink'));
```

```css
#contentDivImg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerDivImg">

  <a id="imageDivLink"><img src="https://teams.connect.te.com/sites/BPDev/PublishingImages/attention1.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="contentDivImg">This demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.his demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.his demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your
  div dynamically via JavaScript.his demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.his demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.his demo uses plus and minus
  images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.his demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.his demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.his
  demo uses plus and minus images for hiding and showing your div dynamically via JavaScript.</div>
```

---

Regarding a transition on your collapsing div, you might want to read [this article about transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition), [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition), and [how to apply transitions / animations to an element with JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/).