# Html CheckBox : Change Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

During the developing of an .NET application I have came across a problem.

What I want to do, is to change the background color of a simple Html checkbox, so I have used the following HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" style="background-color: yellow" />
```

This code works only with OPERA, and not with other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Explorer)

So i have used also Javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("check1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
```

and JQuery sintax:

```
$("#check1").css("background-color", "yellow")
```

but the result is the same.

This code works if I use an HTML TextBox.

Can someone help me please ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398462/css-background-color-attribute-not-working-on-checkbox-inside-div Looks like there is an issue with firefox, chrome, and safari that prohibit this. Did a quick search and did not see a solution.

Comment: The only way to change the checkbox itself is to do image replacement for the checkbox, Ex [on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)

Answer (score 4):

Wrap each checkbox into a div and then change the div's background-color.

So it should be like this:

```
<div style="background-color: yellow;">
<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div style="background-color: red;">
<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div style="background-color: green;">
<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/VvHwm/)

Comment: This is technically not what OP wants, but will be the closest thing that can be done.

Comment: Either that or replace the image of the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

It will not work even in the new Opera, so I recommend to wrap it with a div container.

```
<div id="check1_Container">
<label for="check1">Check box 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" style="background-color: yellow" />
</div>
```

Comment: Totally right, I just removed it. 
I just mentioned it, if you want to change the style at runtime based on some logic