# Rails, CSS, form_for checkbox styling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, styling

I want to change the background color of the checkbox after it is ticked. I have:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
   background: green;
}
```

Doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398462/css-background-color-attribute-not-working-on-checkbox-inside-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **custom checkbox** to do this. [iCheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/) or [prettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/)

more [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/15-jquery-radio-button-checkbox-style-plugins/)