# Use database to check a checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a page to view assets with an Edit link. When I click the link it goes to edit_case.php which has a form to edit what elements of the row are in the database as checkboxes. However the boxes do not show them as checked. I have the following code...

```
// get already checked box values 
$repop = "SELECT * FROM case_audit WHERE case_id = $case_id";
$popresults = mysqli_query($dbc, $repop);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($popresults, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

print_r ($row);
```

The print_r does show the whole record row from DB. which is either a 1 or 0, checked || not checked.

The form...

```
<div id="facepics">
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="Facial1" value="<?php echo $row['frontrest']; ?>" >Front at Rest </label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="Facial2" value="<?php echo $row['frontbigsmile']; ?>" >Front Big Smille</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="Facial3" value="<?php echo $row['profile']; ?>" >Profile</label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="Facial4" value="<?php echo $row['subvertex']; ?>" >SubMento Vertex</label><br>
</div>
```

I know I need to turn the 1's to "checked" just not sure how best to do that.

Comment: you can try http://stackoverflow.com/a/28815506/4535386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically `checked="true"` attribute in input creates a checked checkbox.
HTML Code looks like

`<input type="checkbox" checked="true">`

In your case you can do it like:

`<input type="checkbox" name="Facial1" value="frontrest" <?= (intval($row['frontrest']) == 1) ? 'checked' : '';>`

Also note that I changed **value** attribute, with **frontrest** so that you can identify the checkbox uniquely

**EDIT**: I have modified the code

Comment: That just checks all the checkboxes, I need it to only check those boxes which have a value of 1.

Comment: my bad, the current answer should do!

Comment: after a few rounds of testing, that works. Wonderful

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="checkbox" name="Facial1" <?=$row['frontrest']==1?'checked':''?>>`

I often have the same issue where the browser ignores checked="false" and checks all 
so I use

`<input type="checkbox" checked>`