# Add background color to box of checkbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an issue with coloring the check boxes of the checkbox element in my project.
I create checkboxes dynamically and when I create a new one, I would like to give its check box a new random color.
I would like to style those boxes with my function, which returns the randomly generated color in hex code. That works, but the only thing that keeps bothering me, is how to apply this new color (in hex format it is like: "#FFFFFF") to the checkbox? 
I tried with different varieties but ended with no success. I want to solve this issue with Javascript if it is possible.

I would like to have those checkboxes like lets say Google Calendar has to check, which calendars you would like to see.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: show your code, what you have tried so far.

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7398527/5119765

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: As you generate the new checkbox dynamically add a checkbox.style.backgroundColor = '#yourhexcode'; before you append it to the DOM

Comment: This is not possible using the standard HTML checkbox control. You would need to implement a third party checkbox control.

Comment: If you don't mind adding 3rd party plugins, I recommend [iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/)

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ hey man. i did try with it. but didnt had the desired effect.

Comment: @noa-dev tryed with it, before i posted this question and sadly didn't had success with it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i was afraid, that would be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

Please customize CSS where needed.

```js
$.fn.cbColor = function(color) {
 color = color || '#f00';
  
 this
  .addClass('cb')
  .before('<div class="cb-box" style="background:' + color + ';"></div>');
  
  return this;
};

// Apply color to existing checkboxes
$(':checkbox').cbColor('#fd0');

$('#container').append('<br>');

// Apply color for dynamic elements
var $newCb = $('<input id="custom"type="checkbox">'),
$newCb2 = $('<input id="custom2"type="checkbox">');

$newCb
.appendTo('#container')
.after('<label for="custom">custom</label><br>')
.cbColor('#fdf');

$newCb2
.appendTo('#container')
.after('<label for="custom2">custom2</label><br>')
.cbColor('#f00');
```

```css
.cb {
  display: none;
}

.cb-box {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cb + label::before {
  content: '\0000a0';
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.cb:checked + label::before {
  content: '\2714';
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input id="cb1" type="checkbox"><label for="cb1">1</label><br>
  <input id="cb2" type="checkbox"><label for="cb2">2</label><br>
  <input id="cb3" type="checkbox"><label for="cb3">3</label><br>
  <input id="cb4" type="checkbox"><label for="cb4">4</label><br>
  <input id="cb5" type="checkbox"><label for="cb5">5</label><br>
  <input id="cb6" type="checkbox"><label for="cb6">6</label><br>
  <input id="cb7" type="checkbox"><label for="cb7">7</label><br>
  <input id="cb8" type="checkbox"><label for="cb8">8</label><br>
  <input id="cb9" type="checkbox"><label for="cb9">9</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey man. Actually that one worked. I just edited a bit for my case and works as i wanted. i thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the background color of a checkbox.

A possible solution is to create a 'custom' checkbox with CSS and a HTML label.

The trick is to hide the checkbox. The label for the checkbox gets a `::before` psuedo element which you can style.
Now when the checkbox is checked (which is possible due to the label), you update the style of the `::before` pseudo element.

A very basic example:

```
.custom-cb {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}

.custom-cb + label::before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;

  display: inline-block;;
  background: crimson;
}

.custom-cb:checked + label::before {
  background: #2BED14;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j43djbsd/1/

Comment: But how are you going to specify a dynamic color (from his function)? not sure if there is a way where you can edit the css style of a pseudo element.