# Change the color of CheckBox on check or uncheck?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a input field type checkbox and I want to change the color on check and uncheck, I tried  `ng-class = "unChecked =!checked"` like this, but not working for me.

Here is my html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-class = "unChecked =!checked" class="checkbox" ng-model="inventory.productName" ng-checked='true' ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-click="inventory.addRemoveColumn(inventory.productName,'productInfo.productName', 'PRODUCT NAME')" />Product Name
                <br/>
```

Please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

try this. checkbox default value for ng-value-true is 'true' and ng-false-value is 'false'.

```
  ng-class = "{'checked': inventory.productName, 'unchecked' : !inventory.productName}"
```

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.inventory = {productName:false};
})
```

```css
.checked{
    background-color:red;
  }

.unchecked{
   background-color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  
  <div ng-class = "{'checked': inventory.productName, 'unchecked' : !inventory.productName}">
   <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox" ng-model="inventory.productName"  />Product Name
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but I wanted checkbox background color changes has to be happen

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398462/css-background-color-attribute-not-working-on-checkbox-inside-div

Answer (score 0):

try this.
you have to add conditional class.
Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/3020/)

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="inventory.productName" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" /><span ng-class = "{'checked': inventory.productName=='true', 'unChecked' : inventory.productName=='false'}">Product Name</span>
            <br/>
```

Comment: onclick, it is adding unchecked only and after that it is not changing.<input type="checkbox" ng-class="inventory.productName ? 'checked' : 'unChecked'" class="checkbox ng-valid unChecked ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" value="Device Id" ng-model="inventory.deviceId" ng-click="inventory.addRemoveColumn(inventory.deviceId,'deviceId', 'DEVICE ID')">

Comment: Also if you could mark this as answered that'd be helpful to me and to other SO users

Answer (score 0):

change the ng-class to `ng-class="{'unChecked' : !inventory.productName}"`.

That being said do you really need angular/javascript for this? in css you could do this:

```
.checkbox{
/// Styles when unchecked
}

.checkbox:checked{
//// Styles when checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-class = "{'class1':inventory.productName == 'PRODUCT NAME', 'class2':inventory.productName != 'PRODUCT NAME'}" class="checkbox" ng-model="inventory.productName" ng-checked='true' ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-click="inventory.addRemoveColumn(inventory.productName,'productInfo.productName', 'PRODUCT NAME')" />Product Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/waojkkg4/).

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <label ng-class="{'red': inventory.productName == 'false', 'green': inventory.productName == 'true'}">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="inventory.productName" ng-checked='true' ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-click="inventory.addRemoveColumn(inventory.productName,'productInfo.productName', 'PRODUCT NAME')" ng-init="inventory.productName = 'true'"
    />Product Name
  </label>
  <br/>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: I have to change checkbox background color, is it possible

Comment: You can replace the `color` attribute in CSS with that of the `background-color`

Comment: I tried both background-color, background property, it is not taking