# How to change the background color of a checkbox using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a check box on a page:

[image: as shown in this picture.]

I would like the change the white background color to yellow, how can I do it?

Below is the HTML code of that checkbox.

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
   <input id="p-flag" type="checkbox" name="p_required" value="1"> Rrequired?
</label>
</div>
```

I tried

```
.checkbox{
            background-color: yellow;
}
```

But that's not working.

Comment: Try this :   https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/o9sooyra/

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7398462/4699406

Comment: No, it's not what i need. Just need to change the check box background color from white yo yellow. Not the background color of div.

Comment: You can't. At least as far as my knowledge goes. If I find myself in this situation, I'll just create a checkbox myself, using div's and a custom (icon) font (or you can create one that looks like a radio button with just divs). That way, you can make it look exactly like you want it to. Then use jQuery to handle the ticks and all those things