# Label + Input Adjacent CSS Selector not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can get a p+p adjacent selector working, but not label + input. Why could this be?

```css
p+p {
  color: red;
  /* Works fine! */
}

label+input {
    background-color: red;
  /* Doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<br>
<label>Test</label><input type='checkbox'>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h16engzw/

Comment: Are you looking to change the color of the checkmark?

Comment: Sorry I meant to put background color. Just as an example.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398462/css-background-color-attribute-not-working-on-checkbox-inside-div and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388696/how-to-change-the-background-color-on-a-input-checkbox-with-css

Comment: `label+input` is working as it should. We cannot apply the background-color to input checkbox. So try setting the `width`.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/vuwLyqs7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Actually it's working but you are not using the right property

```
label+input {
    background-color: red;
  /* Doesn't work */
}
```

in this code you are trying to give `background-color: red;` to a `checkbox` but you can't give `background-color` to a checkbox.
for example if you will try this:

```
input {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

this will won't work too.

you are using right selector but the wrong property for a checkbox for example try this.

```
label+input {
        height:70px;
    }
```

now the height of checkbox will change.
I hope you got my point.
Please feel free to ask if not.