# alignmnet in radio button list asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, alignment, radiobuttonlist, text-alignment

I'm confused with the alignment setting of the radio button list in asp.net, it shows in visual basic like this.

[image]

But if i compile it, it shows in my browser like this.

[image]

My code for this radio button list.

```
<td align="right" colspan="2">
                        <asp:RadioButtonList TextAlign="left" ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Fixed Cost" Selected="true" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Per Guest Charge" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Percentage" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </td>
```

How come this happened? I want to get the view like in visual basic, please help.

--- Update ---

This is the result if i change the alignment into "right".

[image]

Here's the HTML.

```
<tr>
                    <td align="right" colspan="2">
                        <table id="ctl00_MainContent_RadioButtonList1" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="1" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_0">Fixed Cost</label></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="2" /><label for="ctl00_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_1">Per Guest Charge</label></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="3" /><label for="ctl00_MainContent_RadioButtonList1_2">Percentage</label></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you tried setting `<asp:RadioButtonList TextAlign="right"` - you have `TextAlign="left"`?</strike>

I think your result HTML (being `<table>` in your addition above) is not guaranteed - ASP.NET may emit `<span>` in other cases/browsers.

Your best option seems to be assigning a CssClass `<asp:RadioButtonList ... CssClass="yourClass">` in combination with some jQuery or direct styling of the possible elements.

See [this broader discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997342/why-does-asp-net-radiobutton-and-checkbox-render-inside-a-span) and also [the accepted answer in this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1089664.aspx/1).

Comment: yes i have tried in TextAlign="right" and it give me weird view

Comment: Can you extract and show the actual HTML that's sent to browser.