# jQuery validation for checkbox always required IE8 bug

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using jQuery v1.9.1 and jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.11.1.

I have defined `data-rule-required="true"` on form items that are mandatory to set `validation-required`.

Somehow the validation always tries to validate the checkboxes when they are not required or are even explicitly set to not be required (`data-rule-required="false"`), only on IE8.

Every other browser are fine!

Anyone knows why or if there is a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out why (and worked out a fix)... because the data attributes did not end up on the actual input element.

Related: [Why does ASP.Net RadioButton and CheckBox render inside a Span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997342/why-does-asp-net-radiobutton-and-checkbox-render-inside-a-span)