# Getting Tool tip of the Radio button in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button, tooltip

How we can achieve to get the value of tooltip of the Radio button in javascript? I tried this method

```
document.getElementById('<%= rbSelectedIds.ClientID %>').title
```

but i am getting blank value only. please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the ID is correct? because it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/8S2we/

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Yes. I am using the right id of the control. except i am using <asp:RadioButton> control. Not the <span> control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET radio button and checkbox are renders inside a span control. So when you put tooltip from server side it will apply to span control.

See why its rendering with span from following link. [Why does ASP.Net RadioButton and CheckBox render inside a Span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997342/why-does-asp-net-radiobutton-and-checkbox-render-inside-a-span)

So you need to find parent element of the control and then you need to get tooltip. Like following.

```
var sParentElement = document.getElementById("%=rbSelectedIds.ClientID%>").parentElement;
var tooltip = sParentElement.title;
alert(tooltip);
```